# Only allow single style to be applied to RichText element

Tags: styles, umbraco

I'm currently maintaining an Umbraco 4.7 site.  I have a document type with a RichText editor data type, using TinyMCE v3 as the WYSIWIG editor.

I have added 2 styles for use (floatLeft and floatRight).  The issue that I'm having is that I only want to add a single style to an element, whereas it looks like the default is to add multiple styles.

E.g. I insert an image and add the style floatLeft, this does as expected and adds class="floatLeft".  Now, if I select that same element and choose the style floatRight and look at the HTML the class is now class="floatLeft floatRight" but I want it to overwrite the floatLeft, not append to it.  Is it possible to ensure that only 1 style is added at a time?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](http://blunderings.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/using-css-classes-for-image-alignment-in-tincmce/) describing how I updated TinyMCE in Umbraco to allow the user to use the "left" and "right" alignment buttons to add CSS classes. You should take a look at it, if you haven't already found another solution.